# awk syntax error calling user defined function

Tags: awk

I get a syntax error:

```
/usr/xpg4/bin/awk: file "./test.awk": line 64: syntax error
Context is:
>>>   printf (", %s", date_value  ( $3, fmt_yyyymmdd ) );   <<<
```

The code fragments are:

```
fmt_yyyymmdd="yyyymmdd";
printf (", %s", date_value  ($22, fmt_yyyymmdd ) );
```

...

```
function date_value(string, format)
{
    return "20150101";
}
```

I am not able to understand where the syntax error is.
A very similar statement (with one parameter only) produces no syntax error and works correctly.

```
printf (", %s", char_value  ( $2) );
```

For me it seems that awk either does not allow calling a user defined function with a parameter being a user defined variable or literal or calling a user defined function with more than one parameter. I am unfortunately not proficient in awk.

Comment: It would make it easier for us (and possibly for you) to spot your error if you put those fragments into a separate minimal example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Is your `printf` inside of an action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is how you call the function. In user-defined functions it cannot exist any space between the name and the parameters, use:

```
printf (", %s", date_value($22, fmt_yyyymmdd ) );
```

Comment: Yes, that is the problem, the OP is simply wrong in asserting that `char_value  ( $2)` does not have this problem. The awk syntax for this, btw, would be `printf ", %s", date_value($22, fmt_yyyymmdd)` since awk is not C and so doesn't need trailing semi-colons and `printf` is a builtin not a function so surrounding it's args in parens is just misleading.

Comment: I have changed the code accordingly and will test it.